# Nano Ledger S in Angular

Tags: angular, webusb, ledgerjs

Today I ran into a problem while trying to connect my NANO Ledger S to my angular app.

I've tried installing [this package](https://github.com/LedgerHQ/ledgerjs/tree/master/packages/hw-transport-webusb#transportwebusb) yet it does not seem to work due to the package throwing some errors.

`Module '"events"' can only be default-imported using the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag`

This can be fixed by putting changing the EventEmmiter import to

`import {EventEmitter} from "events";`

Now at least the app compiles, but when I to access the Devices over the `TransportWebUSB` class a `"ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined"` error is thrown in the console.

I've tried different stuff like following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-custom-webpack-config) tutorial and adding

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'],
})
```

this custom Plugin (idk, thats what the internet told be).

I have tried everything I so StackOverflow is my last resort. Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a while of testing stuff and even switching to another Hardware-Wallet, I finally got it working.

I installed the `buffer` package and in the polyfill.ts I added following lines:

```
let Buffer: any = require('buffer/').Buffer;
(window as any).Buffer = Buffer;
```

It feels like the biggest hotfix in my life, but at least it works now